# why does the 2 computers connection between the server(python) and the client (C# in unity) does not work?

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I am trying to play my unity game from 2 computers (one is the server(python) and one is the client(unity and C#)), but when I try to connect the unity console shows me this error:

"SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

**IF I'LL CHANGE THE CLIENT IP AND WILL RUN IT ON THE SAME COMPUTER, IT WILL WORK**

can you help me figure this out?

this is the client c# code(unity):

```
socket my_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.43.95"), 7777);
        GameMaster.my_socket.Connect(endPoint);
```

this is the server code(in python):

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 7777))
my_socket.listen(5)
(client_socket, client_address) = my_socket.accept()
print str(client_address)+" is connected"
```

Answer (score 0):

except error IP and Port, and you dont precise what protocol you want to use UDP or TCP??

so your Unity Program seems to be in TCP

i think your definition in python is not good (i dont see accept for TCP for example) [you have modified your answer, its okay now]

if you want to do TCP in python you have a sample [HERE](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication)

import socket

```
 TCP_IP = "your IP"
 TCP_PORT = yourPort

 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                      socket.SOCK_STREAM) # TCP
 sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
 sock.listen(1)
 conn, addr = sock.accept()
 print 'Connection address:', addr    

 while 1:
     data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
     if not data: break
     print "received data:", data
     conn.send(data)  # echo
 conn.close()
```

after for performance and if you accept loose of some data, i suggest you to choose UDP..

you'll find lot of example on net in C# and Python for client/server TCP or UDP